# Can CSS style be added multiple times to increase effect

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to control my web page via the HTML as much as possible.

As such, I'd love to be able to do this

```
<p class="largeFont">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont largeFont">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont largeFont largeFont">Hello</p>
```

As you can see, I'm just increasing the number of usages of the same class. This doens't work.

I hoped it would, since .largeFont was

```
.largeFont {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

The concept was each time I called the class, it would apply the font-size of 1.1em. What appears to be happening is that it just applies the font-size to the original value and doesn't re-caculate as it goes.

I then tried to force it inheriting but this didn't work either

```
.largeFont {
    font-size:inherit;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Is my goal achievable with only CSS and HTML?

```css
.largeFont {
    font-size:inherit;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<p class="largeFont">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont largeFont">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont largeFont largeFont">Hello</p>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't support stacking like this, specifying the same class in the DOM a number of times is the same as specifying it once. Specifying the class in a single selector a number of times just increases specificity, but that's a hack and not really relevant here either.

Comment: Stacking is not supported by CSS, maybe you should add another class and create some conditions based on other classes added to the same element.

Comment: _Of course_ this doesn’t work. And that has little to do with “stacking” - if you had applied `font-size: 1.1em` three times using three _different_ classes, the result would still be the same. It does not work, because `em` is relative to the font size of the _parent_ element - and the parent of an element does not change, no matter whether you slap zero, three or five-thousand classes on the element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider another utility class combined with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) like below. You only need to write the *base* value once and the utility classes can also be used with other properties in the same way.

You can also rely on inline style to change the variable if you don't want to define all the multiplier

```css
.largeFont {
  font-size: calc(1.1em * var(--x, 1));
}

.x2 {
  --x: 2;
}

.x3 {
  --x: 3;
}

.x4 {
  --x: 4;
}
```

```html
<p class="largeFont" style="--x:0.5">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont x2">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont" style="--x:2.4">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont x3">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont x4">Hello</p>
<p class="largeFont" style="--x:5">Hello</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I'd like to hearn more. In order to Google search, I need to know what term does `--x` have? They look like CSS variables?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions yes they are CSS variable. I am using the variable `--x` to calculate the font-size and each time I modidfy it with another class. It's your multiplier

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions here is a useful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: it's a fancy way of writing multiple css selectors :) `.largeFont { font-size:1.1em } ; .largeFont.x2 { font-size:2.2em } ; largeFont.x3 { font-size:3.3em}`

Comment: @MihaiT that you can easily maintain since you have to change the base value in only one place ;) and you can consider the `x*` classes with other properties

Comment: Isn't this just a fancier way of writing an inline font-size? You still have to specify the size on the element itself, not in styles.

Comment: @Nit you don't have to explicitely write the inline style using font-size .. you simply change a variable to do this which will avoid you having to define the font-size that you can change in one place for all the elements. This is the purpose (as per my understanding) of the question: To increase the main font-size by adding more classes or another way

Comment: The point being that you're either a) rewriting values everywhere which is why no one realistically uses inline styles, or b) writing what's essentially fixed classes anyway, just with a different syntax.